# Bootstrap navbar position

Tags: react-bootstrap

During my project, I have used a bootstrap navbar. When I scroll my page, it is also scrollable. But I want, it will be fixed on top. That's why I am using sticky="top" property. But, It is still scroll with page.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Navbar component without any additional properties:

```
<div style={{ height: "300vh" }}>
  <Navbar bg="dark">
    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  </Navbar>
</div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-germain-eclx3h

FYI: "fixed" property does exactly the opposite of what you want:

> Create a fixed navbar along the top or bottom of the screen, **that
> scrolls with the page.**

(https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbar-props)